# How to specify an instance class when deploying a Google App Engine application as a single JAR?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I have an application which I deploy as a single JAR file to the Google App Engine Standard Java 11 environment (the application is Open Source, available at https://github.com/OndrejSpanel/Mixtio). I would like the application to use instance class F2 instead of the default F1. When I have tried to provide my own app.yaml by specifying at the command line, I got error "All .yaml files must have unique service ids.":

`gcloud app deploy --project mixtio backend/target/scala-2.12/mixtio.jar backend/web/WEB-INF/cron.yaml backend/web/WEB-INF/app.yaml`

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [D:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmt01m6jp\app.yaml] and [X:\OpenSource\Mixtio\backend\web\WEB-INF\app.yaml] are both defining the service id [default]. All .yaml files must have unique service ids.

This is how the default configuration generated by the Google Cloud when using single jar deployment looks like, as seen in the App Engine console:

```yaml
runtime: java11
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
network: {}
```

How can I configure parameters like `instance_class` for an application deployed as a single jar?

Comment: This might happen when it reads the `app.yaml` twice

Answer (score 2):

Try passing argument [`--appyaml`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--appyaml) `=backend/web/WEB-INF/app.yaml`, in order to be more explicit. Also see: [the default service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/configuration-files#the_default_service). When using the predefined `*.yaml` file-names, one probably doesn't have to specify them, as it is already known what they are meant for.

If you have multiple applications to deploy, just run eg.:

```
gcloud app deploy service-name-app.yaml
gcloud app deploy app.standard.yaml
```

The instance class to deploy is being defined per [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/config/appref), by parameter `instance_class`.

[Defining Runtime Settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) also explain it.

Comment: Great. I had to remove cron.yaml for this to work and deploy it in a separate step, but other than that it seems to work.

Comment: Just one clarification: one needs to use `--appyaml=backend/web/WEB-INF/app.yaml` - you might want to reformat the answer to match this.

Comment: This may depend on the current working-directory, from where `gcloud` runs; these examples seem to assume that the `*.yaml` is present in the same directory. When only passing a single one `*.yaml`, this is being interpreted as positional argument `--appyaml=` (one does not really need to get explicit).

Comment: That is true, but I do not think you could use `--appyaml backend/web/WEB-INF/app.yaml` without the equals sign, not you can use the app.yaml name alone when you already provide the jar name.